# Using an (Items?)Control to manage a collection of UserControls with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, itemscontrol

### Question:

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for; to simply add a collection of views (UserControls) to a control whilst having a consistent MVVM structure?  Is an ItemsControl the way to go, or should be have a different approach?

### Problem

I have a collection of MVVM projects (with usercontrol mainviews) that I want to present in another control that can animate transitions between them.  I have a horizontal listbox across the top of the control functioning as 'tabs' which are bound to the collection of views.  The main body of the control shows a single view bound to the selected item of the list box and animates transitions when a new tab is selected.

[image]

My concern is having the collection of views as part of the new control's viewmodel doesn't make much sense in the MVVM paradigm and it would be more usable if the usercontrols could simply by added straight into the control almost as if it was a panel.  This would lead me to think something like ItemsControl is the way to go and could be used like this:

```
<CustomItemsControl>
    <UserControl1>
    <UserControl2>
    <UserControl3>
    <UserControl4>
</CustomItemsControl>
```

Then have content that looked something like this.

```
<ItemsControl.Template>

<StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="Tabs" Height="35" SelectedIndex="0"
        ItemsSource= >> The binding for the ItemsControls Collection <<
        SelectionChanged="Tabs_TabSelected">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="1" 
                             Columns= >> Binding to Collection.Count <<
                />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>

    <TransitionCtrl Name="TransitionControl" CurrentView="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=Tabs}" />

</StackPanel>

</ItemsControl.Template>
```

From the examples I've looked at the ItemsControl isn't intended to be used in this way.  Any suggestions to point me in the direction of what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you using a particular MVVM framework?

Comment: The UserControls I want to add all used mvvm-lite, but they are entirely stand-alone and all I want to do here is add them to a meta-view.  I feel it would be strange to add a group of views into a view model seeing as I don't want to manipulate their data in any way.  I just want to add them to another control that will flick between them, it doesn't need to know anything about them.

Comment: How is this different from a `TabControl`? To me it seems like you're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: The TabControl doesn't lend itself to easily restyle and animate in the way I need.

Comment: Are the Type s of each UserControl.DataContext same?

Comment: No, they all have their own view models

Comment: @JoshC `The TabControl doesn't lend itself` - How does it not? I can achieve what you're asking here with a TabControl in 5 seconds. Otherwise be more specific in what you need that can't be achieved with it.

Comment: @HighCore I've never used TabControl before this project so my perception of 'easy' is probably different.  I have read its not simple to animate between the content of tabs smoothly.  I also want the tabs to be touch friendly and eventually have slide functionality (use swipe to slide between tabs) is this something that is achievable with the TabControl?  I have read it is not very flexible, but again, haven't actually used it in depth myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using PRISM [view injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff921076(v=pandp.20).aspx) technique. The best approach would be using TabControl as a region and inject the main view when each module loaded. Since tab is not built as a region, you may need a custom region adapter as explained [here](http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2010/07/04/prism-and-wpf-custom-tab-region-adapter-part-01.aspx).

```
<TabControl Grid.Row=”1″ Grid.Column=”1″
        cal:RegionManager.RegionName=”TabRegion” Name=”TabRegion”>
```

From every module,

```
public void Initialize()
{
    regionManager
        .AddToRegion(“TabRegion”, new FirstView())
        .AddToRegion(“TabRegion”, new SecondView());
}
```